# Concurrent Web Service Requests Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a .asmx Web Service.
Under WebMethod i have the following code :

```
Seller s = new Seller();
var a = s.GetSellerListing(Seller, PageNo);
SaveASINS(a);
```

This code performs some heavy mechanism to fetch data from different apis, calculate them and then save them on Database.

According to my understanding if lets say 10 concurrent requests are being sent on this API, it will create 10 different instances and will perform the tasks and save them on DB. It should be the simple scenario according to my understanding but in real environment it is only able to handle on request at a time if i send two requests the 2nd request is not able to connect to the API.

Do we have to manage threads for concurrent requests? or do we have to do some configurations?
I am new to this, Please share your thoughts about multiple requests and how they are handled.
Thanks

Comment: it really depends on the code implementing `GetSellerListing` and `SaveASINS`. Put some traces in your code, such `Console.WriteLine("I.m here, thread id = {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedId)` and try to understand what are the parts of code waiting for other ones. Also, be sure that calls are not enqueued on the client side (do they come from different clients or from one single client?)

Comment: What do you mean when you say the 2nd request is not able to connect to the API? do you get an exception?

Comment: Different clients means, i have tried from different as well same client. Same issue. Yes i got an exception.

Comment: Ok one more point. 1 request takes around 1 min or so to process.
so is that the reason that for 1 min it blocks the webmethod and api is not available for other requests?

Comment: What is the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: Exception message :
Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.greystone.Service1.GetSellerListing(String Seller, Int32 PageNo)